# Dont understand ninject and injecting

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a class, which contain my actions (any logic):

```
public class socActions 
{
    public void Choose(int elem) 
    {
        switch(elem) ... CalcA(elem) || CalcB(elem) ...
    }
    public void CalcA() 
    {

    }
    public void CalcB() 
    {

    }
    public void CalcC() 
    {

    }
}
```

So, in my program, when i get elem value, i use it like:

```
(new socActions()).Choose(elem_val);
```

Okey, but in socActions class methods, i'd like to have a connection with my repository or make any other dependency injection.

1. If i add IRepositoryMy repositoryMy to constructor, then i couldn't
   create classes as above, bcz its need now constructor with argument
   IRepositoryMy.
2. If i try to make injection in field, it doesn't work
   (property = null).
3. If i try to make injection in methods (CalcA,
   CalcB) it doesn't work too.

How i really should make this task (inject class, for example repository)? Don't want to mark everything in my application as static :(

WinForms, C#, Ninject 3

**Edit:**

```
public class socActions
{
    [Inject]
    public IGridProcessor _GridProcessor { private get; set; }
```

so, in method its null:

```
public void UpdateInfo(...)
{                
    ...
    this._GridProcessor.Refresh();
}
```

In other classes, where i inject IGridProcessor to class in constructor, everything fine.
In Program.cs:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new TwttModule());
        var form = kernel.Get<Main>();

        Application.Run(form);
    }

    public class TwttModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IGridProcessor>().To<GridProcessor>();
        }
    }

   public static class AnyClass 
   {
        public static void Act() 
        {
            ....
            (new socActions()).Choose(elem_val);
        }
   }
```

How should i inject IGridProcessor to socActions?

Comment: Show us your ninject code please, that's the crucial bit

Comment: A class where you choose what action to take according to a passed in value appears to me to be a code smell. You should probably have a base class or interface and several classes implementing the differences.

Comment: Still can't understand what should i do and could i inject in field?

Comment: Are you looking to ninject an instance of socActions based on a enum value or what 'configuration' problem are you wanting ninject to solve for you?

Comment: I want to inject IGridProcessor to socActions

Comment: There is no answer for my question? :(

Answer (score 0):

When using constructor injection, you don't construct your classes directly, but rather ask ninject for an instance. Based on how you've configured ninject, you get a new instance, or a singleton instance, etc.

From their docs:

```
Samurai warrior = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
```

Comment: So, how i should inject in my case?

Comment: Ninject will inject. You just ask for its constructor. The whole point of injection is that is no longer your concern.

Comment: You advice me create static kernel?

Comment: Read the ninject documentation. That often helps.